# Prime number finding program using bool values

Tags: c++, boolean

I am trying to write a program in C++ that, given a data file that includes random integers, identifies each integer as prime or not prime, and counts the integers. Here is what I have so far:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
    {
  int number;  //number to be tested
  int  count = 0;  //count of integers in file
  cin >> number;
  while (cin)
    {
      bool prime = true;
  if (number <= 0)
    {
      prime = false;
    }
  else
    {
      for (int i=2; i<number; i++)
      if (number % i == 0)
         { 
           prime = false;
           break;
         }
    }

  if (prime = true)
        cout << number << " is a prime number." << endl;
  if (prime = false)
        cout << number << " is not a prime number." << endl;
  cin >> number;  
  count++;
 } 
cout << "The file contains " << count << " integers" << endl;
return 0;
}
```

The program compiles, but finds all values in a data set as not prime. Here is what I got as output from a data file:

24 is a prime number.
13 is a prime number.
18 is a prime number.
-25 is a prime number.
42 is a prime number.
0 is a prime number.
2 is a prime number.
The file contains 7 integers

Any suggestions? Am I using the bool values correctly?
Thank you

Comment: Thank you all for the responses, it works now!

Comment: Just something that speeds up checking if a number is prime without a list of all the primes less than it.  You check `number % i` for `1<i<number` but you only need to check it for `1<i<sqrt(number)` where the square root has been rounded down to the nearest integer if it was not already an integer

Comment: I meant, the square root should be rounded up (not down) because the highest number that must be checked is the square root rounded down

Answer (score 2):

You are using the assignment operator `=` instead of the equality comparison operator `==` when checking if `prime` is true or false.  (You should also use braces for your `for` loop.)

Heads up that you can check the factors until `prime/2` (or `sqrt(prime)`, see below) since nothing greater than half of a number can be a factor of it!

Comment: What I wanted to say is that if you try all odd numbers plus the number two to see if any of them can divide "number", you can stop at sqrt(number), because if you haven't found any divisor up to then, you won't find it.
16 / 8 wouldn't be tested because 16 / 2 would be tested earlier and it would have stopped the search

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
if (prime = true)
        cout << number << " is a prime number." << endl;
```

is assigning "true" to variable "prime". As a expression, an assignment operation returns the value being assigned, so the expression inside the if evaluates as true and hence, prints that the number is prime.

You have to change = by == . An old trick to avoid these mistakes is to change the sentence as this:

```
if (true = prime)
        cout << number << " is a prime number." << endl;
```

Then the compiler had warned you about the obvious error.